# Timer, BackGroundWorker and ReportProgress

Tags: vb.net

I have a UI that I use to send Stats out of an evening.

The UI enables manual sends of the stats both to a Distribution Group and to Individuals, I also then have a 'scheduled send' that you set a timer for and a Timer Ticks until the present time matches that set in the timer.

When the times match this calls this:

```
Public Shared Sub ProcessDailyStats(ByVal Arguments As List(Of String))

    DailyStats_BGW.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    DailyStats_BGW.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

    AddHandler DailyStats_BGW.DoWork, AddressOf DailyStats_BGW_DoWork
    AddHandler DailyStats_BGW.ProgressChanged, AddressOf DailyStats_BGW_ProgressChanged
    AddHandler DailyStats_BGW.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf DailyStats_BGW_RunWorkerCompleted

    DailyStats_BGW.RunWorkerAsync(Arguments)

End Sub
```

Now when this sub is called via the 'Button' on the MainForm from either an Individual or Distribution Group send the ReportProgress Event works fine.

I use the ReportProgress Event to update a small log, when fired from the Timer the same sub and subsequent ReportProgress events do not update the RTB.

Please note the RTB is in one Class (MainForm) and the Timer and BackGroundWorker are in another class (DailyStats). Why is this working when pressing a Button on MainForm, but failing using a Timer within the DailyStats Class.

FYI the Job finishes properly and I get the resultant email, this is just simply an issue of the RichTextBox not updating during processing.

If you need any more code please ask.

Cheers

Comment: Which Timer, the System one or the Forms one?  Is there an error message?

Comment: No Error Messages, it is a System.Timers.Timer that I call. As I say it goes through fine, but ReportProgress doesn't fire at all.

Comment: BackgroundWorker does not know which of the threads in your program is the "special" one, the one that you used to create your Form object.  It assumes that the thread that called RunWorkerAsync() is the anointed one.  No problem when you use the button, big problem when you use System.Timers.Timer since it fires its Elapsed event on an arbitrary threadpool thread.  Use a synchronous timer instead, System.Windows.Forms.Timer in a Winforms app.

Comment: @HansPassant I'll give that a try now.

Comment: @HansPassant if you can put that as an answer please I will accept that as the solution. Thank You very much.